# python MIME attaching multiple attachments to a multipart message

Tags: python, mime

I am trying to attach multiple attachments to a `email.mime.multipart` object:

```
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message['Subject'] = 'test'

for i in range(10):
    title="<h2>{}</h2>".format(i)
    message.attach(MIMEText(title,"html",_charset="utf-8"))
```

Here I can check that the payload contains the 10 elements:
`message.get_payload()`
I can see the list of 10 elements, which seems correct.

However when I send the email with the following code:

```
MAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
MAIL_USER = 'xxx@gmail.com'
MAIL_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
MAIL_REPICIENTS = ['xxx@gmail.com']

smtp = SMTP(MAIL_HOST)
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login(MAIL_USER, MAIL_PASSWORD)
smtp.sendmail(MAIL_USER, MAIL_REPICIENTS, message.as_string())
smtp.close()
```

The email contains only the last element of the list.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s because you are attaching 10 different messages. Why you want is to attach one message. Change your code to this:

```
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message['Subject'] = 'test'
html = ''

for i in range(10):
    title="<h2>{}</h2>".format(i)
    html += title

message.attach(MIMEText(html,"html",_charset="utf-8"))
```

Comment: Hi thx, yes works thx! But why is it called multipart then if only 1 attachment can be attached? My approach seemed in line with what i found in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.attach

Comment: It is called multiparty because you can have multiple versions of the message attached, eg: a plain text and an html. The message attached last is assumed to be the one that is preferred. So when you attached multiple html messages, all it did was display the last one.